# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def insert(array):
    connection=sqlite3.connect('images.db')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cnt=0
    while cnt != len(array):
            img = array[cnt]
            print(array[cnt])
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', (img))
            cnt+= 1
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

When I try `insert("/gifs/epic-fail-photos-there-i-fixed-it-aww-man-the-tire-pressures-low.gif")`, I get an error message like in the title (the string is indeed 74 characters long).

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

---

<sub>The same problem occurs with `MySQLdb` and many other popular SQL libraries. See [Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when trying to use a string in a parameterized SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359) for details.</sub>

Answer (score 588, accepted):

You need to pass in a sequence, but you forgot the comma to make your parameters a tuple:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', (img,))
```

Without the comma, `(img)` is just a grouped expression, not a tuple, and thus the `img` string is treated as the input sequence. If that string is 74 characters long, then Python sees that as 74 separate bind values, each one character long.

```
>>> len(img)
74
>>> len((img,))
1
```

If you find it easier to read, you can also use a list literal:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', [img])
```

Comment: We are plenty of advanced coders that have made that mistake, so no need to feel stupid. :)

Comment: This bit me, too. If "advanced coders" are fooled by this, it means it is unintuitive. IMHO it would be more natural if execute() took a single value instead of a single-valued tuple if there's only one ? in the query. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @user465139: The `%` operator on `str` does that kind of magic—it treats a tuple as multiple values, but a `str` (or any other kind of iterable) as a single value. But that causes confusion far more often than it solves it, which is why almost nothing else in the stdlib attempts that kind of magic.

Comment: using `%s` is also not recommended for security concerns - https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem happened when the number of columns are not same as the inserting values.

For example:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(',ySQL.db') 
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    sql =   "INSERT INTO mytable (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            
    project = (Y1, Y2)

    print(project)
    c.execute(sql, project)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This is going to raise an error because number of X (X1, X2, X3) are not same as number of Y (Y1, Y2). So, your columns should have the same number as inserted values.

Answer (score 0):

You get confused by the fact that you are dealing with a *single column data* only  but the syntax is compatible to deal with several columns at once, hence the reason to cast your string into a, i.e., tuple.

You could fix it with `zip`: `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', zip(img))`.

To avoid multiple `execute`-calls you can store the strings in a list and update your table in a single call with `executemany`:

```
def insert(array):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('images.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cnt = 0
    imgs = []
    while cnt != len(array):
        img = array[cnt]
        print(array[cnt])
        imgs.append(img)
        cnt += 1

    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', zip(imgs))
```

`executemany` is rows-oriented and `zip` turns the "columns" of `imgs` into rows