# I can't get ? instead of %s to work on an insert with python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I can't get ? instead of %s to work on an insert with python mysqldb.

I try

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO project (project) VALUES (?) """, ('ham'))
```

but I get

```
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

works fine if I simply substitute ? with %s

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It uses string formatting operator `%s`. Use that only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The `mysqldb` adapter only supports the `format` and `pyformat` parameter styles.

The [Python DB API 2.0 specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) supports [5 different `paramstyle` parameter styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) but it is up to the exact database adapter implementation what they support. The [`mysqldb` project documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) tells you what styles are supported by that adapter, and `qmark` is not one of them.

If you are trying to write SQL suitable for multiple database adapters, you'll most likely have to deal with more issues than just the parameter style. Consider using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead, which can generate SQL for you that is more database agnostic (up to a point).

Comment: Is there any way of automatically sanitizing the input like with ? for the python mysqldb? Or just python in general?

Comment: @user1170304: Why do you ask? Are you trying to write SQL suitable for different database adapters?

Comment: @user1170304: You *can* run a `.replace('?', '%s')` on your SQL string, but if there are any `?` characters in the query that are *not* placeholders, you'll have a harder parsing job on your hand.

Comment: The `%s` parameter style will sanitize the input just like the `?` in the call - provided, of course, that you pass your SQL parameters as parameters to the `execute` method: do not pre-format the string with the `%s` with the `%` operator before making the method call.

Comment: @jsbueno: The OP is not doing that; the exception comes from the MySQLdb adapter, which *internally* implements the parameter handling using string formatting.

Comment: I just want to avoid errors when inputting something like 'don't'

@jsbueno I'm not sure what you mean by "that you pass your SQL parameters as parameters to the execute method"

Comment: @user1170304: Then why not just use `%s`? Those are SQL parameters. Don't be fooled by the fact that the syntax is the same as string interpolation in Python; it's not the same functionality here.

Comment: I have used %s but I get an error when i try and input something like 'don't' because it isn't sanitizing the input.

Comment: @user1170304: Use them as SQL parameters; `cur.execute("""INSERT INTO project (project) VALUES (%s) """, ('ham',))` will work just fine.

Comment: @user1170304: Note that that doesn't use `execute(sql % values)`; it uses `execute(sql, values)`.

Comment: @user1170304: The only difference is the *style* of the SQL parameter placeholder. The meaning is *exactly the same*.

Comment: yes it will but something like 'don't'  which is a value taken from a form will fail becuase it is not sanitized. I want to input values that are automatically sanitized. Is this possible?

Comment: @user1170304: That is what SQL parameters **do**, they sanitize the input and quote it correctly. MySQLdb uses SQL parameters in exactly that fashion, provided you use them correctly.

Comment: @user1170304: You didn't share what you tried. It works just fine when used correctly.

Comment: sql = """ INSERT INTO conditions (conditions) VALUES %s """

cur.execute(sql, (string))


where string = 'don't'

Comment: @user1170304: There are two errors there; you need parenthesis: `VALUES (%s)` and you need to make the second parameter a *tuple* (requiring a comma).

Comment: @user1170304: `sql = """INSERT INTO conditions (conditions) VALUES (%s)"""`, then `cur.execute(sql, (string,))`.

Comment: @user1170304: For the latter problem, see [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16856647)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45804/discussion-between-user1170304-and-martijn-pieters)