# Inserting dictionary of python in a single cell in mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have this dictionary in python. I am trying to insert it in mysql db. So I convert it to json using json.dumps, still I get the error that not all arguments converted during string formatting. What should be done?

`{'point': '+', 'time': '00:02', 'acceptedSubmissionId': 42, 'title': 'GNU C++'}`

My code:`cursor.execute("insert into tablename A value %s", json.dumps(user['scoreCard'][i]))`

**EDIT**: I put the json in square brackets, to make a tuple, and it works. Is this correct??
`cursor.execute("insert into contest_"+str(id)+" ("+str(unichr(i + 65))+") values (%s)", [json.dumps(user['scoreCard'][i])])`

Comment: Is A the column name? Even then you've got to put parentheses around your column list and your value: `INSERT INTO tablename (A) VALUE (%s) ...

Comment: @VMai : I dont think it is necessary. Anyways, I tried and it still doesnt work

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @VMai: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: A quick google search did lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting Maybe it should be `cursor.execute("insert into tablename (A) value (%s)", [json.dumps(user['scoreCard'][i])])` instead. I'm not firm in Python.

Comment: @Vmai: Yes, I too tried it just now on my own, and it worked. But am not sure if this is the correct JSON formatting. Although in my database, I can see this exactly -> {"point": "+", "time": "00:02", "acceptedSubmissionId": "42", "title": "GNU C++"}

Comment: Select the value and let it be examined by json.load ...

Comment: Yes, It does work. I used json_decode($row, true) in php and then tried to access individual keys and it showed the value. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
cursor.execute("insert into tablename A value {0}", json.dumps(user['scoreCard'][i]))
```

The notation %s will be deprecated soon.

Comment: AFAIK, this syntax isn't supported by any database libraries -- http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle.  Maybe you are thinking about regular string formatting with `%` vs. `.format` ... But even then, I don't know of any plans to deprecate `%` anytime soon.