# Pushing results of Imaplib to Mysql database leading to "TypeError"

Tags: python, mysql, imaplib

I am trying to create a local database of my email using Python. 
I am using Imaplib to read email from Imap server. My target is to push the extracted emails to a local MySql database in the format "SUBJECT", "SENDER", "RECEIVER".

I have built up the code that creates a local database, read emails(with specific message). 
I am not sure how to craft the code that pushes the results to my Database "EMAIL".

**EDIT** : I have managed to solve my previous issue of parsing mails and adding it to database. Now I am stuck with type conversion error for Mysql.
Here is my new script:

```
 def parse_email(raw_email):
email_complete = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
email_to = email_complete["To"]
email_from = email_complete["From"]
email_header = email_complete.items()
email_msg = get_first_text_block(email_complete)
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", # your host, usually localhost
                    user="admin", # your username
                    passwd="pwd", # your password
                    db="sec_crawl") # name of the data base
con.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO email VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
(buffer(str(email_to)),buffer(str(email_from)),buffer(str(email_header)),buffer(str(email_msg))))
con.commit()
```

On executing this script, I get the following error :

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Here is the part of script that creates the database:

```
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMAIL")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE email(email_to TEXT,email_from TEXT,email_header TEXT, email_msg TEXT)")
con.close()
```

I am not sure about the error. I did search some previous questions

[Python MySQLdb TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

But the problem is still there.
I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use %s instead of ? like this

```
con.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO email VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
 (buffer(str(email_to)),buffer(str(email_from)),buffer(str(email_header)),buffer(str(email_msg))))
```

'?' are typically used with prepared statements which MySQLdb doesn't support.

Comment: Perfect. This worked. I got confused with declaration in SQLite.