# MySQL, python update row if null

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database which contains 7 fields, field 1 is unique and the rest are not. However field 2 and 3 could be null. I am trying to update the database with information from a csv file to fill in the nulls but I cannot get it to work. The field could be null or the field could already contain the information.

```
db=mdb.connect('localhost','username','password','db')
cur=db.cursor()
inputinfo=csv.reader(open('Insert.csv','r'),delimiter=',')
for row in inputinfo:
    inserthostNames=("""update fileSort set hostNames=values(hostNames) where hostNames is not null""")
    cur.execute(inserthostNames,row[1])
    insertIPAddress=("""update fileSort set IPAddress=values(IPAddress) where IPAddress is not null""")
```

It does not work and gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
    insertTADDM()
  File "test.py", line 47, in insertTADDM
    cur.execute(inserthostNames,row[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Edit1:

```
for row in inputinfo:
    inserthostNames=("""update fileSort set hostNames=hostNames where hostNames is null""",row)
    cur.execute(inserthostNames,row[1])
    insertIPAddress=("""update fileSort set IPAddress=IPAddress where IPAddress is null""",row)
    cur.execute(insertIPAddress,row[2])
```

this gives the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'str'
```

Edit 2:

```
for row in inputinfo:
    inserthostNames=("""update fileSort set hostNames='%s' where hostNames is null""")
    cur.execute(inserthostNames,(db.escape_string(row[1])))
    #insertIPAddress=("""update fileSort set IPAddress='%s' where IPAddress is null""")
    #cur.execute(insertIPAddress,row[2])
db.commit()
```

gives me:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SERVER2'' where hostNames is null' at line 1")
```

THE APOSTROPHE RETURNED

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Since you're not providing the error that you are getting, I will bet that it has to do with the wrong `SQL` syntax in your `update` statements. The first one for example should be `update fileSort set hostNames=hostNames where hostNames is not null`.

Also note that you're not `execute`ing the second statement.

Comment: it will execute but not do anything but i can see the null fields and i can find the value in the csv file

Comment: I've updated to include the error

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting

Comment: that works for lists when i try it it says that im using a tuple, ill edit to show what im doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `execute` function contains a parameter, `row[1]` but there is no place for substitution in your query string. Also, parameters must be passed as a sequence. Additionally, if you want to fill in the nulls, then the `where` condition should be `where hostNames is null`.

Further more, since `hostNames` might contain special characters, you might want to escape it using `conn.escape_string`

You might want to change your query to:

```
inserthostNames=("""update fileSort set hostNames='%s' where hostNames is null""")
cur.execute(inserthostNames,(db.escape_string(row[1])))
```

Comment: this spits out the error _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SERVER2'' where hostNames is null' at line 1")

Comment: What's the value of your `row[1]`? You should strip the unnecessary `'`

Comment: if i look in gedit the value is SERVER2 but i see what you mean by the unnecessary ' ill have to look how to get rid of that

Comment: it now passes the inserthostNames but hits insertIPAddress saying the same error where it finds a ' but ive done the same thing again and it still hits the error

Comment: Then do the similar thing for the IP address.

Comment: I did, it still hits the error, so i edited out the ipAddress and let it run, it ran all the way through but it did not actually insert anything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are talking about but I've had some problems with mysql interpreting nulls and fixed it by changing the source file.  I modified the source file to replace blank cells with the string "Null". The program writes a new file so your initial file should be unmodified.  The file that is written isn't perfect but can easily be modified in excel to have the proper format.  Then I used a local infile to reload it into the database.  Hopefully this helps and let me know if you have an issue with the code.

```
import csv

output= open("practice_output.csv","w")  #Replace practice_output.csv with desired output name.


with open('practice.csv',"rU") as csvfile:  #replace practice.csv with input file name.
    ACS = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    count= []    # A rough way to track how fast the program reads through lines.
    for row in ACS:
        row=','.join(row)
        row=row.split(",")
        list = []
        for item in row:
            print item
            item=str(item)
            if item != "":
                #output.write(item + ",")
                list.append(item)
            else: 
                item= item.replace("","NULL")
                #output.write(item+",")
                list.append(item)
        list=','.join(list)
        count.append("1")
        print len(count)    ###  Allows to show when each line is completed when running very large files.  
        output.write(list+"\r\n,")

output.close()
```