# MySQL - Returning NULL even though it contains an integer

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, cgi

I'm using Python CGI and MySQL (phpmyadmin). I'm trying to run this SQL statement in python: (tk_journey = 620 for this example - where the %s is)

```
SELECT tk_id, tk_seat_number FROM tickets
        WHERE tk_journey = '%s'
        ORDER BY tk_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It works perfectly in phpmyadmin and displays what it should (which is this):

```
tk_id tk_seat_number
 94         2
```

However, when I run this through a python script it returns None/NoneType for each.

I've tried using this: `SELECT MAX(tk_id), tk_seat_number FROM tickets WHERE tk_journey = '%s'` but that gave the same result.

I tried to use %s without the quotes but it also generated an error - in mysql syntax. I also tried closing and opening the database connection - didn't work.
I've tried researching this problem a lot but to no help.

Here is the python code:

```
def getSeatNum(jid):
    statement = '''SELECT tk_id, tk_seat_number FROM tickets
        WHERE tk_journey = '%s'
        ORDER BY tk_id DESC LIMIT 1;'''
    cursor.execute(statement, jid)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    seat_num = row[0]
    return(seat_num)

seat_no = getSeatNum(jid)
```

jid = 620.
The db connection works fine as there are several other functions similar to this selecting/inserting information into tables, but this one seems to be failing?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is what I am meant to do. This got marked as a duplicate of this question: [Python MySQL TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting). I never got this TypeError. If the program ran without generating an error - it just returned 'NULL', which in turn affected a later program as the variable would just be 'NULL'. The errors I would get were the SQL syntax error as shown above and various Python errors when I was fiddling around to get it to work. Not this TypeError one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `cursor.execute()` must be a tuple containing the values to fill in all the placeholders in the query. Even if there's only one placeholder, you need a tuple. So it should be:

```
cursor.execute(statement, (jid,))
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! That worked, i can't believe it was that simple and I'd spent so long trying to figure it out! :')