# Psycopg2 - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert the value of the variable test_text into a Postgres 9.6 database, each time the database_insert function is triggered.

I'm using Python 3.6 and psycopg2 v 2.7

If I use the below code without the placeholder: e.g replace %s with 'test' and remove , (test_text) - it works as I would expect...

```
def database_insert(update):

    test_text = 'This is some test text'

    with psycopg2.connect("DB CONNECTION DETAILS ARE HERE'") as conn:

        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s);", (test_text))

        conn.commit()

        cur.close()

    conn.close()
```

However when the function trys to insert the value of the test_text variable using the %s placeholder, I get the error below...

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s);", (test_text))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any help on where I am going wrong with this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when trying to use a string in a parameterized SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/why-do-i-get-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-w)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a subtle issue here.

You need a comma to make a tuple not just the parens/brackets.

So simply change to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s);", (test_text,))
```

And you should be good!

Comment: I can't believe it was such a simple fix - I've literally been searching for hours on how to fix this, Thank you Bernie! I will mark as correct answer as soon as this lets me - Merry Christmas!

Comment: looks like this execute tries to insert the entire record into the first column, maybe it only works with single column tables? `ProgrammingError: column "some_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record`