# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to insert this data into MYSQL with python.

```
import MySQLdb

inputString = "acs dc sasa"

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user123","password123","db123" )

cursor = db.cursor()
query = """UPDATE nextShow (num, information) VALUES (0, %s)"""
cursor.execute(query,(inputString))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute

```
query = query % args
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users...\pyNextShowData.py", line 9, in
>
> ```
> cursor.execute(query,(inputString))
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240,
>   in execute
>
> ```
> self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line
>   52, in defaulterrorhandler
>
> ```
> raise errorclass(errorvalue)
> ```
>
> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

How to fix it? Please teach me

Comment: Basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting, though I'm sure there was an exact dupe for your question as well. The thing is that `(inputString)` is not a tuple, but just an expression in brackets. A comma would make it a tuple: `(inputString,)`

Comment: I thank you for the answer.
I had already tried
If I add the comma --> `cursor.execute(query,(inputString,))`
 I get this error.

**_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(num, information) VALUES (0, 'acs dc sasa')' at line 1")**

Comment: You start off with an UPDATE, but the rest of the syntax corresponds to INSERT. Perhaps you meant the latter?

Comment: Yes you are right.
Thank you, now it works :)