# Flask, trying to read in data from mysql db (not all arguments converted during string formatting)

Tags: mysql, flask

Trying to create a page with a barchart. I'm using Flask framework and MySQL database.

```
@app.route("/grafiek")
def chart():
    data = []
    years = optimize_list(get_data("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM tbldata"))
    print(years)

    sql = "SELECT cast(sum(Number_employees) as signed) FROM  tbldata"
    sql += "WHERE year = (%s) GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year, month ASC"
    print(sql)

    for year in years:
        data_part = optimize_list(get_data(sql, year))
        data.append(data_part)

        print(data)

        labels = optimize_list(get_data("SELECT DISTINCT month FROM faillisementen.tbldata"))
        titels= "Number Employees in faillisementen"
        colors = ['red', 'green']

        return render_template("chart.html", data=data, labels=labels)
```

On running  I get the error:

```
getting data
SELECT cast(sum(Nulber_employees) as signed) FROM  tbldata
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I assume the error has to do with these lines:

```
sql = "SELECT cast(sum(Number_employees) as signed) FROM  tbldata"
sql += "WHERE year = (%s) GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year, month ASC"
```

How do I fix this please?

Update:
I get the error  "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when the second line with the (%s) is not used.  When that line is being used then I get a different error.

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (2011) GROUP BY jaar, maand ORDER BY jaar, maand ASC' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the (%s) in the second line:

sql += "WHERE year = (%s) GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year, month ASC"

If you remove that line does it work?

Please see [Python MySQLdb TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a different way of putting in data from my database into my chart.

Thank you nonetheless.

```
def get_faillissementen(jaar):
    connectie = mysql.connect()
    cursor = connectie.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("select sum(Aantal_faillissementen) from data where jaar = '%s' group by Maand ", jaar)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # alles eruit halen
        # Als je maar 1 gegeven hebt => fetchone()
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    db_data = []

   for row in results:
        db_data.append(int(row[0]))


    cursor.close()
    connectie.close()

    return db_data

@app.route("/chart")
def chart():
    jaar_2011 = get_faillissementen(2011)
    jaar_2012 = get_faillissementen(2012)
    jaar_2013 = get_faillissementen(2013)
```

This made it much easier.