# Python mysqlclient: Passing JSON string to execute() results in 'not all arguments converted during bytes formatting' error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, singlestore

Hi I'm currently using mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1 and I'm trying to write a Python function to write serialized JSON strings into a blob column in a table by calling a procedure with executemany statement

Example Python dictionary:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 2,
  "key3": {
    "arr1": [1, 2, 3],
    "arr2": [-1,-2,-3]
  }
}
```

The snippet from the function:

```py
from bson import json_util

bulk_docs = []
cnt = 0

write_query = 'call db.update_proc(%s)'

for json_doc in docs:
    if json_doc is not None:
        bulk_docs.append(json_util.dumps(json_doc))
        cnt += 1
    if cnt == 20:
         mysql_cur.executemany(write_query, bulk_docs)
         mysql_conn.commit()
```

It's returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" line 204, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

I went into debug mode and found out that in line 202 in that MySQLdb/cursors.py where it executes the following,

```
else:
    args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
```

it will take my JSON string and split it like so:

```
(b"'{'", b'\'\\"\'', b"'k'", b"'e'", b"'y'", b"'1'", ...
```

Is there a better approach to passing a list of JSON serialized strings to a executemany statement?

Answer (score 0):

hope!!!!

use json library to dump data and load

eg : bulk_docs.append(json.dumps(json_doc))

```
import json 
doc=[]
data=['hi','hope','this','helps']
for info in data:
  info=json.dumps(info)
  doc.append(info)
```

Comment: I've tried the json library with no luck :\

Comment: send your input data and expected data

Comment: The input is that example Python dictionary in my original question. The trouble comes in when it steps into the cursor.execute() function and splits the string by character. I think I found a temporary solution though. Doing `doc.append([info])` seems to do the trick for me. So that when that `args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))` executes it just converts the list of just the JSON string to tuple, instead of splitting the JSON string by char.

Comment: i hope the same

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a duplicate of this issue: [Python MySQLdb TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

My fix for this example was to change the list `bulk_docs.append()` to

```
bulk_docs.append([json_util.dumps(json_doc)])
```