# Check if user exists before inserting into Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How do i go about something like this, I want to check if a user exists against a table in python, and if the user exists , it should report that the particular user exists, else if the user does not, it should register (insert the user into the mysql database)

So far, this is what my code is looking like

```
@app.route('/api/user',methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    _json = request.json
    _email = _json['email']
    _phone = _json['phone']
    _password = _json['password']

    fullname = 'NULL'
    custID = '123456'
    
    #conn = mysql.connect()
    #cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    checkuser = 'select email from accounts where email = %s' # check if user exists here.
    query = "insert into accounts (email,phone,fullname,password,custID) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
            #query = "update empData set name = %s, email = %s, phone = %s, address = %s, salary = %s"
    bindData = (_email, _phone, _password , fullname , custID)
    cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    output = {'email':_email, 'phone':_phone, 'fullname':fullname, 'custID':custID, 'message':'ok'}

    return jsonify({'result':output}),200
```

How do I go about something like this, I started out flask a week ago.

**Edits**

This is what i been working on, but it complains about indentation. Code is looking like so

```
@app.route('/api/user', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    _json = request.json
    _email = _json['email']
    _phone = _json['phone']
    _password = _json['password']

    fullname = 'NULL'
    custID = '123456'
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    checkuser = 'select email from accounts where email = %s'
    bindData = (_email)
    cursor.execute(query,bindData)
    acc = cursor.fetchone()
    if acc:
        return jsonify({'message':'User exists, Please Login'})
    elif:
        query = "insert into accounts (email,phone,fullname,password,custID) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
        bindData = (_email, _phone, _password , fullname , custID)
        cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
    output = {'email':_email, 'phone':_phone, 'fullname':fullname, 'custID':custID, 'message':'ok'}
    
    return jsonify({'result':output}),200
```

**Edits 2**

So I made some Edits for the second time, it just fires back Error 500 when i am testing with Postman.

My code is looking Thus

```
@app.route("/api/user", methods=["POST"])
def create_user():
    _json = request.json
    _email = _json["email"]
    _phone = _json["phone"]
    _password = _json["password"]

    fullname = "NULL"
    custID = "123456"
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from accounts where email = %s', _email)
    acc = cursor.fetchone()
    if acc:
        return jsonify({"message": "User exists, Please Login"})
    else:
        query = "insert into accounts (email,phone,fullname,password,custID) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
        bindData = (_email, _phone, _password, fullname, custID)
        cursor.execute(query, bindData)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        output = {
            "email": _email,
            "phone": _phone,
            "fullname": fullname,
            "custID": custID,
            "message": "ok",
        }

    return jsonify({"result": output}), 200
```

it says this is where the Error is according to the Log

which is here `cursor.execute('select * from accounts where email = %s', _email)` Is there something i missed?

Comment: Don't you have a unique index on email? With an unique index you don't need to check if the entry allready exists. Just insert the data, in case of error 1062 report "user exists"

Comment: No, not really. What i succeeded in doing was to check if the user exists and if it does, it flags it as an error. Let me Edit my answer to show u what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work!
I had to do some reading and searching thru, this gave me an idea of what to do. Its like searching thru a List or something in the Database to get adequate results

So i saw this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740359/python-mysqldb-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting

Then changed my code from this

```
cursor.execute('select * from accounts where email = %s', _email
```

to this :

```
cursor.execute('select * from accounts where email = %s', [_email]
```

And it gave the actual response I wanted it to give. Just in case it should help someone.

Thanks everyone.

**Edit**

Below is what the code Looks like after the work arounds.

```
@app.route("/api/user", methods=["POST"])
def create_user():
    _json = request.json
    _email = _json["email"]
    _phone = _json["phone"]
    _password = _json["password"]

    fullname = "NULL"
    custID = "123456"
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from accounts where email = %s", [_email])
    acc = cursor.fetchone()
    if acc:
        return jsonify({"message": "User exists, Please Login"})
    else:
        query = "insert into accounts (email,phone,fullname,password,custID) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
        bindData = (_email, _phone, fullname, _password, custID)
        cursor.execute(query, bindData)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        output = {
            "email": _email,
            "phone": _phone,
            "fullname": fullname,
            "custID": custID,
            "message": "ok",
        }

    return jsonify({"result": output}), 200
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar program a few weeks ago which is the same concept but a slightly rudamentary approach, I hope it helps.

Assuming the SQL connection was properly setup and in my case using the table "userdata" and searching the column "username"

```
def login(user):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = '%s';" %(user,))
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    if record != None:          # record = ('<user>','<password>')
        if record[1]==password:
            login_success()
        else:
            login_failed()
    else:
        data_not_found()
```

This activates after the button press.

```
login_btn = Button(root,text='Login',command=lambda:[del_failed_msg(),get_input(),login(name)])
```

So, here, the search result in the database should be a single record which I have stored under a variable 'record' using fetchone() function.
The fetchone() function has returned a tuple of my desired search which I can traverse to get my desired values within the record.

Comment: In your edit, I think the line 13 is incorrect.

Comment: instead of 'query', it should be 'checkuser' in "cursor.execute(query,bindData)"

Comment: See what my code looks like this time in second Edits.

Comment: @Mike You missed one apostrophe in line 11 `cursor.execute('select * from accounts where email = %s', _email)` before %s' That is the fuss I guess.

Comment: do you mind showing me what i am not doing rightly, cos what you wrote looks like what i put in my code

Comment: do `cursor.execute("select * from accounts where email = '%s' ;" %(email,) )`