# Can't update table using "executemany" in python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, executemany

I have to update simple table using below expression:

```py
cur.executemany('UPDATE earths SET population=?, density=?, tilt=?, "land area"=?, dobe=?, livity=? WHERE sid=' + str(dc['sid']) + ' AND nr=' + str(dc['nr']), v)
```

Printing the content it gets:

```py
('UPDATE earths SET population=?, density=?, tilt=?, "land area"=?, dobe=?, livity=? WHERE sid=15821 AND nr=8',
 ['1360425627', '2.79', '17.33', '486857065.504', '17.88371', '0.08'])
```

The error I get is:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 10 supplied.
```

I don't know how the program sees 10 values from 6 element list. Any ideas? The table is ok - inserting data one by one gives ok values. It looks

```sql
UPDATE earths SET population=1360425627, density=2.79, tilt=17.33, "land area"=486857065.504, dobe=17.88371, livity=0.08 WHERE sid=15821 AND nr=8
```

Comment: Try supplying numbers without speech marks?

Comment: My code says `len(v)
Out[838]: 6`

Comment: I got types mismatch with no details if apply without quotes, but I assume it has nothing with this issue, because inline code works.

Comment: This is the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091723/programming-error-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work if you used `execute()` and maybe this is what you want to do, but for `executemany()` you should use a tuple of tuples as the 2nd argument, because this is the point of `executemany()`, to execute the same statement many times and each time supply a different list of parameters:

```
v = [('1360425627', '2.79', '17.33', '486857065.504', '17.88371', '0.08'),]
cur.executemany('UPDATE ...', v)
```

Comment: Strangely, tuple `v
Out[853]: ('127830056', '0.58', '22.06', '218662597.847', '37.27435', '0.41')` of len 6 make error: `ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 9 supplied.` I hide 3 fields somewhere!

Comment: @Peter.k use execute() and not eecutemany() if v=('127830056', '0.58', '22.06', '218662597.847', '37.27435', '0.41')

Comment: Ok. Found it: As You said: ` [('127830056', '0.58', '22.06', '218662597.847', '37.27435', '0.41')]` works. I used `[]` on `tuple`, Now it has len=1, but inserts those values.

Comment: @Peter.k but if what you want is to execute the statement only once then you should use execute() and v = ('127830056', '0.58', '22.06', '218662597.847', '37.27435', '0.41').

Comment: Now i get it and everything is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`executemany` expects a nested sequence and interprets `v[0]` as the first sequence to insert.

It's as if you had used `execute(..., v[0])`.

It says "10 arguments supplied" because `v[0]` happens to be a string of length 10.