# Python - Insert filename into database with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I've created this table in my database:

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE VIDEO(ID VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)""")
```

and what my script is supposed to do is to read all the files in a folder and put the filename into the VIDEO table (the filename is the ID and primary key):

```
def AddVideo(video):
    con = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\Francesco\\Desktop\\db\\Database.db")
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON""")
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO VIDEO(ID) VALUES(?)""", (video))
```

But I got this error:

```
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO VIDEO(ID) VALUES(?)""", (video))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 26 supplied.
```

Now 26 is the the number of characters in the filename that I'm trying to add, all files are read from the folder with this:

```
for video in os.listdir(VIDEO_FOLDER):
  AddVideo(video)
```

Comment: Can you please check if the solution provided here helps you: [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta

Comment: Was exactly this the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the cur.execute() function takes a *tuple* of parameters as its second argument. It's treating your `value` parameter as a tuple, which in this case is 26 characters long. To make it a tuple, just add a comma!

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO VIDEO(ID) VALUES(?)""", (video,))
```