# How to insert string into the BLOB column in Python

Tags: python, string, sqlite, blob

I am trying to insert string into BLOB column using sqlite3 in Python. I saw some examples using binary file but I am trying to do it without files. Here is my code-

```
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)

# my string
ablob = 'Hello world!'
sql_statement = 'INSERT into table VALUES (?)'
c.execute(sql_statement, [sqlite3.Binary(ablob)])
c.commit()
c.close()
```

After execution, new column with the string is added but not in a blob column.
Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want a string or a blob?

Comment: I want to insert a string into a blob

Comment: A string is not a blob. Do you want to have a string value or a blob value? What is the purpose of the values in this column?

Comment: I want to convert my string to binary data so I can insert it into a blob column

Comment: You can insert the string directly into the blob column.

Comment: This is what I did in the example I gave but it didn't work.

Comment: Works for me. Would you please tell use what actually happens?

Comment: I can see it in the blob column but as a string and not as a binary data inside a blob. When I look at this db in 'SqliteBrowser' I see in the blob column the actual string, and I want to see 'blob' and to see the string only when I click on it. I hope it's clear.

Comment: The code you've shown inserts a blob. Try `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(BlobColumn) FROM MyTable;`. You have a problem with SQLiteBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

First, your syntax for `execute()` is wrong:

```
c.execute(sql_statement, [sqlite3.Binary(ablob)])
```

- You should use parentheses for the tuple instead of []
- if you provide only one element in the tupl `sqlite3.Binary(ablob)` to `execute()` you should add a comma to be recognized as tuple. See answers to [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

The correct syntax would be:

```
c.execute(sql_statement, (sqlite3.Binary(ablob),))
```

I tested the following code:

```
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)

# my string
ablob = 'Hello world!'
sql_statement = 'INSERT into table VALUES (?)'
c.execute(sql_statement, (sqlite3.Binary(ablob),))
c.commit()
c.close()
return 0
```

And it works for me. I created the table with the command

```
CREATE TABLE table (blob BLOB);
```

and after executing the script there is an entry in this table:

```
sqlite> SELECT * from table;
Hello world!
```

Finally, why do you use `sql_statement = '''INSERT into table VALUES (?)'''`? I removed two apostrophes each and the script works as expected with this line, too:

```
sql_statement = 'INSERT into tab VALUES (?)'
```

Comment: When I open the database using SqliteBrowser tool, I see that it didn't saved in a blob column.

Comment: `execute()` works just fine with a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: @shonlev123 I think I mixed something up with the `execute()` function. Can you try something else instead of the SqliteBrowser?
If you open a terminal and go to your database and open it with `sqlite3 database.db` followed by your `SELECT` statement?
Which Python and SQLite version are you using?