# SQLite3 python extracting data by month

Tags: python, date, sqlite

I have a table populated with values, one being date in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I'm trying to print all "cost" values by month. So,

```
def SumByMonth():
    usrDate = raw_input('Enter month: ')
    sql = '''SELECT cost FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%m', date) = ?''', (usrDate)
    month_cost = [t[0] for t in cur.execute(sql)]
    print month_cost
```

This code gives me this error:

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode
```

So I figure the SQL command isn't actually extracting anything? What am I missing here?

Comment: Well the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16856730/2380332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with line

```
sql = '''SELECT cost FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%m', date) = ?''', (usrDate)
```

You need to write SQL query in string or unicode format like the error states

Here is a correct code :

```
def SumByMonth():
    usrDate = raw_input('Enter month: ')
    month_cost = [t[0] for t in cur.execute("SELECT cost FROM Finance WHERE strftime('%m', date) = ?", (usrDate,))]
    print month_cost
```