# Can't use question mark (sqlite3, python)

Tags: python, sqlite

This code is stucks:

`c.execute("select * from table_name where num=?", a)`

And this is not:

`c.execute("select * from table_name where num={}".format(a))`

So what is wrong? Colmn in table is `int` and `a` is `int` too

Comment: So how big is the database? And why the nested query; why not just use `c.execute("select count(*) from users where id=? and lvl=?", (id, lvl))` (using sql parameters to avoid SQL injection)?

Comment: Data base is not too big, about 50 rows with ~9 columns
id and lvl source is safe. Anyway i'll use '?' in future, thx

Comment: How have you determined it is 'stuck'? Just executing this query won't actually fetch any rows yet, for example.

Comment: print("1") below is not shown

Comment: And you are certain the `c.execute()` itself is reached?

Comment: There's no way anyone is going to be able to help you with only the information provided. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hmm i think i got my problem. I cant use '?' mark.
This code is works:

`c.execute("select * from accounts where num={}".format(num))`
And this is not:

`c.execute("select * from accounts where num=?", num)`

Comment: Solved (there is invalid type, should be typle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it works the same on sqlite, but in mysql in order to use the `select from select` form, you must give each table an alias, like this:

```
select count(*) from (select * from users as b where id=ID and lvl=LVL) as a
```

This might be the source of your problem.