# Error while getting data out of sqlite3 database with python3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to get data out of a sqlite database but I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
self.con = sqlite3.connect("config.db")
self.cur = self.con.cursor()
self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (PCFolder TEXT, ServerFolder TEXT)")
self.con.commit()
dpop = input("Dir path on the PC->") #dpop means "dir path on pc"
dpos = input("Dir path on the server->")
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO config VALUES (?, ?)", (dpop, dpos))
self.con.commit()
self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM config WHERE PCFolder=?", (dpop))
name = cur.fetchall()
print(name)
```

Terminal

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM config WHERE PCFolder=?", (dpop))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The 
current statement uses 1, and there are 11 supplied.
```

Comment: You need to pass the single parameter as a tuple e.g. `(dpop,)` with the extra comma. Currently it's taking your string and breaking it down into a sequence of 11 characters rather than treating it as a single string.

Comment: @roganjosh works, thank you

Comment: Indeed I found it really hard to find a good title..

Comment: Searching for the exception is always a good start. 1st match in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta

Comment: Oh sorry, next time