# Dynamically Inserting into a Sqlite Database errors

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have the following code

`cur.executemany("INSERT INTO "+tablename+" (name,"+item+") VALUES(?,?)",(data,))`

Which dynamically inserts values from `data`
 Now i have two problems :
 If i use the syntax as `VALUES(?,?)",(data))` without `, after data` 
 i would get this error

```
Error Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 4 supplied.:
```

which is solved only by using the syntax as `VALUES(?,?)",(data,))` with `,`

It solves this issue and data gets inserted into the table.
But it creates another problem which i can't Query the DB and use something like

`cursor = cur.execute("select * from "+tablename+" where name="+name+"")`

i would get this error :

```
Error no such column: deek:
```

**I Don't know how to Query the DB using the above mentioned Syntax.**

I got the above syntax from 
[sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

Complete Code for reference :

```
import sqlite3
import sys
tablename='asfoor'
table_data=['Name','a','b','c']

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('dbtrials.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tablename+"")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE "+tablename+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,Name TEXT, "+table_data[1]+" TEXT, "+table_data[2]+" TEXT, "+table_data[3]+" TEXT )")



    name='deek'
    item='a'
    data=[name,item]
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO "+tablename+" (name,"+item+") VALUES(?,?)",(data,))
    cursor = cur.execute("select * from "+tablename+" where name="+name+"")
    for row in cursor  :
              print(row)


except sqlite3.Error as e:

    print ("Error %s:" % e.args[0])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: it is the same , if i use VALUES(?,?)",(name,item)) i still get the same error `The current statement uses 2, and there are 4 supplied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because you forgot to put quotes around the string. It should be:

```
cursor = cur.execute("select * from "+tablename+" where name='"+name+"'")
```

But it would be better to use a parametrized query:

```
cursor = cur.execute("select * from "+tablename+" where name= %s", (name,))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `executemany` expects *iterator of sequences or mappings* as a second argument.
Your input should look like this: `data = [[name, item]]`

So the query you expect:

1. `deek` , `a` (2 args)

Without the inner list it takes the string as a sequence of chars so your queries are:

1. `d`, `e`, `e`, `k` (4 args)
2. `a` (1 arg)