# Mysql insert not working in python with %s

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import csv import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="4g_hs_upgrade" ) 
mycursor = mydb.cursor() 
sql = "INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES %s" 
val = 'John' 
mycursor.execute(sql, (val)) 
mydb.commit()
```

Here is the error I'm getting :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "csvreader.py", line 13, in mycursor.execute(sql, (val)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: You should probably indent and format your code to make it readable. What exactly did you expect to happen? You have `%s` in the string, but the string isn't followed by a `%` and an expression to substitute something for the string? See here https://pyformat.info/ for a more modern and Pythonic way to do things. And keep in mind that in the current version of python you can also write `f'some {x} string'` to format it with `x`, instead of `'some {} string'.format(x)`.

Comment: If you trying to use %s to put in some string, use it this way - sql = "INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES %s" % your_variable

Comment: Use `(val, )` to make it a tuple; note that `(val) == val` because parentheses are interpreted as arithmetic grouping, e.g. `1 + (2 + 3) + 4`. On the other hand, `(1, )` makes a tuple, just like `(1, 2, ) == (1, 2)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `%s` in the query string won't work as expected, you could follow it with `% replacement_string`, but it appears you want to `executemany()` and have MySQL do the replacement on the fly. This is the safer and better way to do this, so you are on the correct path.

The correct syntax:

```
import csv 
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="4g_hs_upgrade") 
mycursor = mydb.cursor() 
sql = "INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)" 
val = 'John' 
mycursor.execute(sql, (val)) 
mydb.commit()
```

Note that the value `'John'` doesn't sound very logical for a column named `num`, but I'm merely following your example.

You were missing the parentheses, which caused confusion because it suggested you were looking to use the Python `%s` string replacement functionality, while you were probably after this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Comment: What is wrong here?
sql = """INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)"""
val = [('Peter'),('Amy'),('Hannah')]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

Comment: Your problem there is that `('Peter')` is not a tuple, but just a string in parentheses. Python only understands an expression in parentheses to be a tuple if it includes commas. So, `sql = """INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)""" val = [('Peter',),('Amy',),('Hannah',)] mycursor.executemany(sql, val)` - it's an annoying gotcha, where we're paying for brevity with clarity.

Comment: i tried executing 
"""INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)""" val = [('Peter'),('Amy'),('Hannah')] mycursor.executemany(sql, val) in Python3 and it worked fine.

Comment: It's quite possibly that `executemany` is more flexible and deals with single values as if they were single value tuples.

Answer (score 2):

See below. Note parentheses around the `%s` in `sql`. Note `params` tuple, i.e., trailing comma after the single value.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)"
val = 'John'
params = (val,)
mycursor.execute(sql, params)
```

See [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) for the MySQLCursor.execute() Method

Comment: Thanks Justin, eventually i was missing that comma in set

Answer (score 1):

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="4g_hs_upgrade" ) 
    mycursor = mydb.cursor() 
    sql = "INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES %s" % ('John',) 
    mycursor.execute(sql, (val)) 
    mydb.commit()
```

You must do it like this, `% ('John',)`

If you have a list of values you may do it like this,

```
values = ['John', 'address1']
sql = "INSERT INTO test (num, address) VALUES (%s)" % (','.join(values))
```

Comment: yeah it is working that way but i want to user executemany() as i have a large dataset and this can't be used

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
why my code is not working this way?
source: w3school