# ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 40 supplied

Tags: python, sql, input, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I have a user input where I want to enter a userID and retrieve the songID's that are asscociated with that user. I'm having trouble with this because of errors around the cursor.

[image]

Database that im trying to retrieve from.

```python
import pyodbc    
import MySQLdb
import sqlite3 

MusicData = sqlite3.connect("D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3")

randomVariable = raw_input('Enter something: ')
cursor = MusicData.cursor()
MusicData = "SELECT songID FROM train WHERE userID=?"
result = cursor.execute(MusicData,randomVariable)
print result
```

When i enter the userID i expect to get the SongID's associated with that user however I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-edd40392d38f> in <module>()
     25 cursor = MusicData.cursor()
     26 MusicData = "SELECT songID FROM train WHERE userID=?"
---> 27 result = cursor.execute(MusicData,randomVariable)
     28 print result
     29 

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 40 supplied.
```

Answer (score 3):

Should already be answered here: [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

The short of it though, is the second parameter in your execute call is expected to be a tuple instead of just the value, so wrap randomVariable as follows:

`cursor.execute(MusicData,(randomVariable,))`

Hope this helps!

Why it thinks that you supplied 40 parameters is because it is iterating over your input string thinking each character is a parameter you meant to fill in.

Comment: Thankyou for the help and explanation! the only problem is now that I get the error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'". Im using jupyter notebook and it doesnt give the error the first time I freshly run the program and i can query the database but if i input it again it throws the error.

Comment: @T.Gilmour Using the same variable for the database connection and a string is a bad idea...