# sqlite3 select where name and value are variables

Tags: sqlite, select

in python my code to fetch data from the table is as follows:

```
posts = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT * FROM post WHERE (? = ?) ORDER BY created DESC', (name, value)
    ).fetchall()
```

name and value are variables depending on what the user clicks on the page.

The code won't work... how should it be written???

Addon:

Searching for a solution I bumped into the following:

```
def get_posts(name, tag):
    posts = get_db().execute(
        """SELECT * FROM post WHERE ({} = ?)""".format(name), (tag,)
    ).fetchall()
```

But didn't work for me too...

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM post WHERE '+ name + '  = ?) ORDER BY created DESC', (value)`

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply... but it didn't work... you forgot to open the bracket before closing it... so I did: 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE ('+ name + '  = ?)... But the response is "Incorrect number of bindings"

Comment: Did you remove `name` from the end?

Comment: def get_posts(name, tag):  
    posts = get_db().execute(   
         'SELECT * FROM post WHERE ('+ name + '  = ?) ORDER BY created DESC', (value)).fetchall()

Comment: I have to mention... name is a variable, not a column.
The columns are author, title, body.

Comment: I know that. But the name will have column name assigned to it right?  You want to query the table with both column name and value passed dynamically to the query. Try to add comma after `value`  As `(value,)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta

Comment: I did... but it won't work as well

Comment: get_posts method has tag parameter but that's not used. Is the value variable declared somewhere else? Or you mistyped it in place of using`tag`?

Comment: yes ... I mistyped... it's value not tag... mistyping happened here not in the application

Comment: I am not sure what you found on Google about this error, but I found https://techoverflow.net/2019/10/14/how-to-fix-sqlite3-python-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-statement-uses-1-supplied/. According to it you need to have pass value as an list element. So can you try `[value]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chetan for your support and patience... 
I tried, but no... didn't work... I edited the post ... please have a look

Comment: @user90939 I don't know Perl, but in your latest edit, I'm guessing `{}` is a place-holder to tell `.format()` where to put `name`. If so, you appear to have an extra closing-brace, at least in your edit. Another tip: at least while debugging, form the SELECT statement before `.execute` so you can print/see its value and make sure that part has worked as intended.

Comment: As TripeHound suggests, you have a bug in your (Python) code with the extra brace.  More importantly, what doesn't work?  How does it fail?  What did you expect to happen?  Without answers to these questions in the body of the question itself, our answers will be guesses.

Comment: @Anon: Thanks for ur comment... the extra brace was a typo mistake. I am implementing this function in a flask project. It may be possible that flask doesn't allow this because it affects the security.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Flask and SQLite are a not-uncommon combination of tools.  What doesn't work?

Comment: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

This is the response...

Comment: The function you showed us doesn't return anything at all under any condition.

Comment: :) it ends with return posts  
  
Here is the complete function:  
  
    def get_posts(name, tag):  
        posts = get_db().execute(  
            """SELECT * FROM post WHERE ({} = ?)""".format(name), (tag,)  
        ).fetchall()  
  
        if posts is None:  
            abort(404, "Post id {0} doesn't exist.".format(id))  
  
        return posts