# Python SQLite insert data with variable

Tags: python, sqlite

Can't insert variable to sqlite db

```
def new_player(nickname):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/pythonsqlite.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT  INTO Players VALUES (NULL, ?)", (nickname))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
new_player(nickname)
```

I get this error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.

7 is the number of letters in nickname string

Comment: `c.execute("INSERT  INTO Players VALUES (NULL, ?)", (nickname,))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
c.execute("INSERT  INTO Players VALUES (NULL, ?)", (nickname,))
```

this way you supply one-element tuple. Note the comma.

Comment: Bonus +1 for making the binding value a one-element tuple.