# Python: Incorrect number of bindings supplied when EXECUTEMANY

Tags: python, binding, executemany

Trying to pick up some python. I'm quite new to it at the moment.

I created the code below, but it returns an error.

I am able to get it to work when creating a second column and write multiple values to the db but a single value doesn't seem to work. Probably a list, tuple thing, but can not figure out what exactly.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO combination VALUES (?)", combination)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("combinations.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(r"create table if not exists combination (string text)")

combination = []
chars = "abcd"

for char1 in chars:
    for char2 in chars:
        combination.append((char1+char2))

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO combination VALUES (?)", combination)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta please check this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed making the string into a `tuple` when adding to the list. The argument to `executemany` expects a list of iterables, so if you pass it a single string `'ab'` in the list, it will treat it as a 2-item iterator of `a` & `b` - hence the error.

You need to make the string `'ab'` into a 1-item tuple like `('ab',)`. You do this by adding a trailing comma to the expression you're appending:

```
combination.append((char1+char2,))
```

Full code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("combinations.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(r"create table if not exists combination (string text)")

combination = []
chars = "abcd"

for char1 in chars:
    for char2 in chars:
        combination.append((char1+char2,))  # ('ab',) etc.

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO combination VALUES (?)", combination)

conn.commit()
```