# How can i pass different arguments to my function?

Tags: python, sql, database, function, sqlite

0

I am trying to create a function which is reading from my csv file and inserts it in a sql table.

This is my code:

```
def transaction_import(path):
   with open (path, 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       columns = next(reader)
       query = 'insert into transactions({0}) values ({1})'
       query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       for data in reader:
          cursor.execute(query, data)

transactions = transaction_import('../data/budapest.csv')

c.execute("select * from transactions")
transactions = c.fetchall()
for row in transactions:
   print(row)
```

What i want to do is to read several transactions from different csvs. All of them have the same structure and column names. ex: transactions = transaction_import('../Data/Source/ny.csv') transactions = transaction_import('../Data/Source/london.csv')

When I run it I get this error: File "/Users/.../main.py", line 82, in transaction_import cursor.execute(query,(data,)) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: `print(data)` to see what the data is…?

Comment: i want to pass different arguments to my function. I already have print row in there

Comment: The point is that apparently some rows don't contain enough columns. The first step when debugging something is to *output all the values* to see what the code is actually trying to do…

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a comma in @ cursor.execute(query, data)
Also google is your friend, see: [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 74 supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta)

Comment: sorry but where exactly? I have it here: for data in reader:
          cursor.execute(query, data)

Comment: Did you check the link I provided? It's the exact same issue. Compare your code to the one in the solution. Hope it helps