# Why do I get "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied." even though I used a tuple?

Tags: python, sqlite, types, discord.py, tuples

From my Discord bot I'm getting :

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.

The data in the database is `[('123', 'hello world!'), ('111', 'testing lolz')]` and when I run 'search' with '123' as id the bot should reply with 'hello world!'. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta) answer says I used a tuple in the SQLite code. Here is the code for the 'search' command:

```py
@tree.command(name='search', description='search for a message by id!', guild=discord.Object(id=1025197159785693284))
async def search(intr: discord.Interaction, id: str):
    res = cur.execute('SELECT message FROM messages WHERE id="(?)"', (id, )).fetchone()
    await intr.response.send_message(f'message {id} is: {res[0]}')

    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quotes in your parameter `id="(?)"`, so:

```
res = cur.execute('SELECT message FROM messages WHERE id=(?)', (id, )).fetchone()
```