# How do I create a discord.py bot that interacts with Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py, sqlite3-python

I am creating a License Registration Discord.py bot, where I have 2 commands, /register to register your vehicle and /plate for police to look them up. I have created the register command, but I am continiously failing at the plate, one, getting error after error. I have fixed most errors, but this is where I have been stopped:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mali Towers\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\Users\Mali Towers\Desktop\Python\moreboredstuff\licenseplate.py", line 40, in plate
    c.execute('select rblx_name from registrations where license_plate = ?', (license_plate))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mali Towers\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mali Towers\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\Mali Towers\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'plate' raised an exception: ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.
```

This is my code:

```py
import discord, sqlite3
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

conn = sqlite3.connect('regos.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS registrations (
             rblx_name string NOT NULL,
             license_plate string NOT NULL,
             vehicle_name string NOT NULL,
             colour string NOT NULL
             )""")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user}")
    try:
        synced = await tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@tree.command(name = "register", description = "Register your vehicle in-game using it's plate number") #Add the guild ids in which the slash command will appear. If it should be in all, remove the argument, but note that it will take some time (up to an hour) to register the command if it's for all guilds.
async def register(interaction: discord.Interaction, rblx_name: str, license_plate: str, vehicle_name: str, colour: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{vehicle_name} added to vehicle library", description="Vehicle successfully registered")
    embed.add_field(name="Vehicle Name:", value=vehicle_name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Vehicle Colour:", value=colour)
    embed.add_field(name="Vehicle License Plate:", value=license_plate)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    c.execute('insert into registrations(rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour) values(?, ?, ?, ?)', (rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour))


@tree.command(name="plate", description="Search up a registered plate")
async def plate(interaction: discord.Interaction, license_plate: str):
    c.execute('select rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour from registrations where license_plate = ?', (license_plate))
    result = c.fetchall()
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{license_plate} lookup successful")
    embed.add_field(name="result", value=result)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

(yes, client.run("token") is at the bottom, just hidden)

I have attempted to remove the other 3 selectors from the command, as shown:

```py
    c.execute('select rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour from 
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

But, alas, I still receive the same error. I believed that would work because I thought the 'extra 5 bindings' were those, but obviously I cannot count and it turns out it wasn't. I am kind of new to these databases so I am still learning how the mechanics all work, so please help me out here.

Comment: Does your `license_plate` has 6 characters in it by chance?  Try adding a `print(type(license_plate), license_plate)` as the first line of your `plate()` and check what you get.

Comment: @JonSG Yes, I found a question sent to me in an answer posted and it had the root cause, being a simple comma. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16856647/5422841) question will help you as well. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16856730/5422841) should solve your isse. What [JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg) hinted you will explain you why. :)

You should use

```py
c.execute('select rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour from registrations where license_plate = ?', (license_plate, ))
```

or

```py
c.execute('select rblx_name, license_plate, vehicle_name, colour from registrations where license_plate = ?', [license_plate])
```

Comment: How would I be able to extract the output of the rblxuser, licenseplate, vehiclename and colour from it and chop it up into the 4 different categories, because all I'm getting right now is [('testuser', 'AGTEF', 'Ford F150', 'Space Grey')] (random information I entered)