# not sure why I get a syntax error when trying to run a SQL UPDATE query using f strings

Tags: python, sql, database, f-string

I am trying to run a basic SQL query to UPDATE the value for schoolNum from a database called bartonHill, using f strings to put the values in

```py
import sqlite3
name = [input('enter your firstname: ')]


conn = sqlite3.connect('revision.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bartonHill (
    firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
    lastName TEXT NOT NULL,
    schoolNum INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)''')

conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO bartonHill VALUES ('Ollie','Burgess','20314')")
conn.commit()

new_number = tuple[(int(input('enter your new school number')))]
c.execute(f"UPDATE bartonHill set schoolNum = '{new_number}' WHERE firstName = '{name}'")
conn.commit
c.execute('SELECT lastName, schoolNum FROM bartonHill WHERE firstName = (?)',name)
print(c.fetchall())
```

However running this code gives me the error " sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Ollie": syntax error " if i input my name Ollie (which exists inside the database as a firsName)

I have tried changing the datatype of name and new_number but this only changed the error

Comment: There are a lot of strange things in your code. Why is `name` a list? Why is `new_number` a tuple? How did you forget to call `commit` after the update? And why do you use an f-string instead of using the second parameter of `execute` as you did it for your SELECT statement?

Comment: INTIGER? Are you sure the UPDATE is the problem?

Comment: BTW, bartonHill is a very odd table name. Is that table for one school alone? That would be very poor design.

Comment: for why name is a list and new_number a tuple - honestly, not really a good reason (although making name a list solved an issue similar to the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856647/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-sta). As for why i am using f-strings instead, i just wanted to see if it is possible to use them in a similar way as a parameter.

Comment: Using f-strings is insecure - don't so this.

Comment: (to clarify, using f-strings to interpolate values into SQL statements is insecure, because it creates a risk of SQL injection; use parameter substitution as described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python))

Comment: Note that SQL injection is not just about *security* but also about *correctness* as you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of point to improve. I made some small changes only, that you can further improve. INSERT always tuple. Change a PRIMARY KEY is possible, but not so easy, google for that. Ask for new values after first initialization of your values. Read the comments above carefully, too!

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('revision.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bartonHill (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    schoolNum integer NOT NULL,
    firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
    lastName TEXT NOT NULL   
)''')
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO bartonHill (schoolNum,firstName,lastName) VALUES (?,?,?); ", (20314, 'Ollie','Burgess'))
conn.commit()

# Ask for changes here
firstname = input('enter your firstname: ')
lastname = input('enter your lastname: ')
new_number = int(input('enter your new school number: '))

c.execute("UPDATE bartonHill set schoolNum = ? WHERE firstName = ?;", (new_number, firstname))
conn.commit

c.execute("SELECT * FROM bartonHill WHERE firstName = ?;", (firstname,))
print(c.fetchall())
```

Output:

```
>>> enter your firstname: Ollie
>>> enter your lastname: Burgess
>>> enter your new school number: 20000
>>> [(1, 20000, 'Ollie', 'Burgess')]
```

or anoter SELECT:

```
c.execute("SELECT schoolNum, lastName FROM bartonHill WHERE firstName = ?;", (firstname,))
print(c.fetchone())
```

Gives you specific values only:

```
(20000, 'Burgess')
```